# What does if [ $# -lt 2 ] mean?

Tags: scripts

I'm new to Unix/Linux. I'm trying to understand the code of the developer before me. Can someone please tell me what does this line `if [ $# -lt 2 ]` mean?

Comment: As a friendly warning to a new bash user, the spaces in that expression (and many others) are important.  The extra space around `[` is not stylistic, and removing it will make the script not work.  :)

Comment: As a friendly note, UNIX and Linux are *not* the same thing. Linux is a *Unix-like* operating system. UNIX is one particular Unix-like operating system (the original one). There are other Unix-like OSes, such as Mac OS X, AIX, Solaris, OpenIndiana, FreeBSD, ... Some of those are certified as conforming to the relevant standards, others are not. Ubuntu is a *distribution* built around Linux, which is very similar to a true UNIX in many respects, but is not certified as conforming to the UNIX specifications. For a short history lesson, see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85189/2465.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling op may be new to both, though.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann Absolutely, but Ubuntu is a Linux distribution, and Linux is not a Unix, only Unix-*like*. Granted, Linux is *quite* Unix-like, but saying "I am new to unix/linux" is a bit like saying "I am new to Mercedes/Renault": it might technically be perfectly true, but there are other ways to state it that would probably be more *meaningful*.

Answer (score 16):

In Bash `$#` expands to the number of positional parameters that have been set.

`if [ $a -lt $b ]` means if the value of a is less than the value of b.

`if [ $# -lt 2 ]` means if the number of positional parameters set is less than 2.

In a working example you would perhaps use this to count the parameters given to a function. If you define a function as:

```
count_words(){
  if [ $# -lt 2 ]
  then
    echo "There are less than two words."
  else
    echo "There are 2 or more words."
  fi
}
```

Then call the function with differing numbers of words, the results would be as follows:

```
$ count_words hello
There are less than two words.

$ count_words how many words
There are two or more words.

$ count_words
There are less than two words.

$ count_words two words
There are two or more words.
```

Comment: Just remember: the `#` in `$#` does not start a comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is a composition of three things:

- `$#` is a shell variable which contains the number of positional arguments to a script or function.
- `[` is not special syntax, but rather the name of a program—it’s an alias for `test`. (Check out `man [` or `man test`.)

  The command line of `[` is parsed as an expression: `[ $# -lt 2 ]` is calling `[` with the arguments `$#`, `-lt`, `2`, and `]` (which is just a visual delimiter). It returns a successful exit code, setting `$?` to `0` if the expression evaluates to true (i.e., if the number of arguments to the script is less than 2) or a failed exit code otherwise, setting `$?` to `1`. You can see this by entering:

  ```
  [ 1 -lt 2 ]; echo $?    # 1 < 2 is true: 0
  [ 2 -lt 1 ]; echo $?    # 2 < 1 is false: 1
  ```
- `if condition; then body; fi` evaluates the command `condition`, and, if it returns a successful exit code, proceeds to evaluate the commands in `body`.

It’s worth noting some things you may encounter:

- The `true` utility always returns a successful exit code, and `false` always returns failure, so you can use them in conditions, e.g.:

  ```
  while true; do
    …
  done
  ```
- `if [ $foo = "yes" ]` won’t work if `$foo` expands to the empty string (`[ = yes ]`), or to a string containing spaces (`[ no thanks = yes ]`). Therefore you’ll often see:

  ```
  if [ "x$foo" = "xyes" ]
  ```

  So that `[` receives a single argument `xno thanks` as the first operand of `=`.
- `[[`…`]]` is a shell *keyword* (not a *builtin*), with special parsing rules to address the limitation above, and which may provide additional features.

Comment: Good amount of additional information there, I always favour `[[` over test.